# Holomorphic vector bundles over $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

Can anyone suggest a good exposition of the classification of holomorphic vector bundles over $\mathbb{CP}^1$? Also does there exist any analytic or more elementary proof of Atiyah's classification of vector bundles over elliptic curves?

Comment: It wasn't clear if you already know the answer: they are sums of line bundles. This is contained what I believe is Grothendieck's first paper in algebraic geometry. If you don't read French you can find a proof in a book by Okonek, Spindler & Schneider, on vector bundles on projective spaces

Comment: For an analytic classification of vector bundles on elliptic curves, formulated in terms of factors of automorphy, check out the work of Iena http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3230